# Spring MVC Controller vs Servlet

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a query regarding how Controllers actually serve the requests..when compared to servlets.

Servlets when instantiated ..have only 1 instance and for each request spawns a thread. How
does Spring MVC controllers serve requests.

Regards

Comment: There is still a Servlet, the `DispatcherServlet` which delegates the handling of the request to the controller (or actually handler).

Comment: yeah i agree that DispatcherServlet acts as a frontcontroller for the whole stack..but my query is specific to the Controller class (@Controller) assume 2 requests reach DispatcherServlet for this controller..how is it being handled?

Comment: That doesn't matter as each request has its own thread. It basically doesn't matter/differ from a single servlet processing multiple requests. The only difference is that the code isn't in the servlet it is delegated.